# Making Firefox developer edition the default browser for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, firefox

I just installed Firefox developer edition using the terminal and it is working allright. The problem is I want to make it my default browser but it is not among my options. I can only see Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 20 (or another *yy* release), which is a different product to the *yy.mm* format 20.04 you possibly mean. Please clarify (Ubuntu has used *yy* releases for a different product since 2016)

Comment: Sorry I meant Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please edit & correct your question  (I can then delete my comment)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would probably be to do this through the terminal, as it will list each installed browser and give you the option to set one as default.

In your terminal, type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

You'll see a list like this:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/microsoft-edge-dev     0         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Choose the item you want to be set as the default.